# Activity has been destroyed at FragmentTransaction.commit()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmenttransaction

I'm trying to dynamically add a Fragment to my `ViewPager` using the common ways I found as a result of some searching, I tried two ways:

the First one is from the Activity that is the parent of the ViewPager :

```
Light_Center fragment = new Light_Center(); // the Fragment Activity
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(fragment, "num_" + i);
ft.commit(); // this is where i got the Exception
```

the second one is from the Fragment Activity itself (Light_Center.Class):

```
FragmentManager childFragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
Light_Center fragB = new Light_Center();
childFragTrans.add(R.id.light_center_fragment, fragB);
childFragTrans.addToBackStack("B");
childFragTrans.commit(); // this is where i got the Exception
```

and the two ways gave me the same Exception at the `commit()` line:

```
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1365)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.automation.isolace.Lighting$11.onClick(Lighting.java:339)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 12:46:04.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
```

I found a lot of questions on **StackOverFlow** that represent the same Exception but neither with the way I'm using.

Comment: Where are you creating the FragmentTransaction? It looks like it is being done while the Activity is finishing.

Comment: @jmcdonnell40 I'm creating it as a result of an onClick and the click action happens in another fragment of the Activity

Comment: Just out of curiosity, change commit() to commitAllowingStateLoss() and see if that works?

Comment: @jmcdonnell40 the same error in the same line in both cases

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is you are beginning the `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` and before you are able to execute `.commit()` your activity or fragment is getting destroyed. I have a similar problem. You are going to need to check your state and make sure things are still around before committing. What else is happening in your app when this error occurs?